# Is there a way in ggplot2 in R to manipulate or customize the display of x axis text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Challenge:I need to automatically (without hard coding) customize x axis text in my graph, as follows. This is exclusively for aesthetic appeal for my users:

1. Two rows of text needed in place of x axis text. First row, displays a sub-category (Role) while the second row (breed) displays a main category. See reprex code data set below
2. Vertical line separating the main categories

See plot 2 titled "Output: This is what I want" to visually see what I want. 
Here is a reproducible example code.

```
require(tidyverse)
bark <- tribble(
  ~breed,    ~value,  ~role,    ~id,
  "Bulldog",   1,       "Dad",   "A",   
  "Bulldog",   1,       "Mom",   "B",
  "Bulldog",   2,       "Ch1",   "C",
  "Bulldog",   1,       "Ch2",   "D",
  "Bulldog",   2,       "Ch3",   "E",
  "Poodle",    1,       "Dad",   "F",
  "Poodle",    3,       "Mom",   "G",
  "Poodle",    1,       "Ch1",   "H",
  "Poodle",    4,       "Ch2",   "I",
  "Beagle",    1,       "Mom",   "J",
  "Beagle",    5,       "Ch1",   "K",
  "Beagle",    1,       "Ch2",   "L",
  "Pug",       1,       "Mom",   "M",
  "Pug",       2,       "Dad",   "N",
  "Pug",       3,       "Ch2",   "O",
  "Pug",       1,       "Ch3",   "P",
  "Boxer",     5,       "Dad",   "Q",
  "Boxer",     4,       "Ch1",   "R"
)
ggplot2::ggplot(data=bark,aes(x=id,y=value))+geom_point()+geom_text(aes(y=1,label=role))+theme(axis.title = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

Output: Not what i want
[image: Output: not what i want]
**Output: This is what i want**
[image: Output: This is what i want]

I'm sure there are few tricks that can help me get there. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'd be best off using `facet_wrap`.

EDIT: to have it completely your way, swap the strip.label with the axis.label:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data=bark,aes(x= role, y=value)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(), strip.placement = "outside") +
  facet_wrap("breed", strip.position = "bottom", nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I wanted. Can you explain what you mean by " to have it completely your way, swap the strip.label with the axis.label". Sorry not sure what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. In the edit I added `strip.placement = "outside"`. It was not there before, hence the strip labels were swapped with the axis labels (the default).

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to put a non-facet based option out there, which is a nested axis guide I wrote at some point and I think comes pretty close to what you want to achieve. The essence of it is to use `"axis_nested"` as the x-axis guide in combination with factor combinations through `interaction()`:

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
library(ggh4x)

bark <- tribble(
  ~breed,    ~value,  ~role,    ~id,
  "Bulldog",   1,       "Dad",   "A",   
  "Bulldog",   1,       "Mom",   "B",
  "Bulldog",   2,       "Ch1",   "C",
  "Bulldog",   1,       "Ch2",   "D",
  "Bulldog",   2,       "Ch3",   "E",
  "Poodle",    1,       "Dad",   "F",
  "Poodle",    3,       "Mom",   "G",
  "Poodle",    1,       "Ch1",   "H",
  "Poodle",    4,       "Ch2",   "I",
  "Beagle",    1,       "Mom",   "J",
  "Beagle",    5,       "Ch1",   "K",
  "Beagle",    1,       "Ch2",   "L",
  "Pug",       1,       "Mom",   "M",
  "Pug",       2,       "Dad",   "N",
  "Pug",       3,       "Ch2",   "O",
  "Pug",       1,       "Ch3",   "P",
  "Boxer",     5,       "Dad",   "Q",
  "Boxer",     4,       "Ch1",   "R"
)

g <- ggplot(data=bark,aes(x=interaction(role, breed),y=value))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = "axis_nested")
g
```

[image]

Then, to put in the few bits to make it look more like your example you can remove the seperator and add the vertical lines. Unfortunately I couldn't come up with a way to not hard-code the vertical lines without some preprocessing.

```r
g <- g + geom_vline(xintercept = c(3.5, 5.5, 10.5, 14.5)) +
  theme(ggh4x.axis.nestline = element_blank())
g
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the ggh4x package. Will explore the other capabilities as well.